# C# Rest call passing certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, rest, ssl

I have a RESTful endpoint that is protected by a certificate which is contained within my windows cert trust store and also in IIS.  I am attempting to send that certificate to the RESTful endpoint to get authenticated and get a response.

So my endpoint is like : https://myrestful.ssl.endpoint/return/some/data

If I attempt to hit the endpoint direct from browser I get 401 no certificate chain in request which is what I would have expected trying to hit directly.  However I am no trying to hit from my .NET code but I am still getting a 401 error.  My current code is as below:

```
        var endpoint = "https://myrestful.ssl.endpoint/return/some/data";

        var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
        {
             ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic 
        });

        var response = client.GetAsync(endpoint).Result;
```

Note the RESTful Endpoint I am hitting from my App hosted in IIS is hosted on Tomcat Server.  I had read the below from this [site](http://pfelix.wordpress.com/2012/12/16/using-httpclient-with-ssltls/)  :

*The first option is to explicitly configure the HttpClient with a HttpClientHandler instance, containing its ClientCertificateOptions property set to Automatic.
The resulting HttpClient can then be used normally: if during a connection handshake the server requires the client certificate, the HttpClientHandler instance will automatically select a compatible client certificate for the user’s personal certificate store.*

However as I still am getting 401 response seems as though I am not sending the correct public cert which I need to the request.  So if I have a cert in IIS with Common Name of my.first.cert - has anyone got the correct way I should be add this certificate to my client request in my code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to lift my certificate with the code below:

```
    private static X509Certificate2 FindSubjectNameInStore(string subjectName,
                                                          StoreName name, StoreLocation location)
    {
        //creates the store based on the input name and location e.g. name=My
        var certStore = new X509Store(name, location);
        certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        //finds the certificate in question in this store
        var certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, subjectName, false);
        certStore.Close();

        return certCollection.Count > 0 ? certCollection[0] : null;
    }
```

So I pass in the subject name of the cert I want.  Still having an issue with connecting to my endpoint but I can post that in another question.